# Isotope filters in Meteor.onRendered not working at first

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor, jquery-isotope

I have a Meteor app, where I load a collection into a Isotope grid. The items are sortable using Isotope's sort function.

My problem is that the filters does not fire when the items are listed the first time. I've put all the Isotope functions inside `Template.CatchesList.onRendered` but somehow I have to navigate from CatchesList page to another page, and then back again before the filters will work.

I've also wrapped the whole thing inside `imagesLoaded`to make sure all of the grid items images is loaded before Isotope render, to avoid any weird floats.

```
Template.CatchesList.onRendered(function() {

$('.grid').imagesLoaded( function() {
// quick  search regex
var qsRegex;

// init Isotope
var $container = $('.grid').isotope({
  itemSelector: '.grid-item',
  layoutMode: 'masonry',
  getSortData: {
    river: '.river',
    species: '.species',
    sex: '.sex',
    weight: '.weight parseFloat',
    date: '[data-date]',
  },
  sortBy: ['date'],
  sortAscending: {
    river: true,
    species: true,
    sex: true,
    weight: false,
    date: false
  },
  filter: function() {
    return qsRegex ? $(this).text().match(qsRegex) : true;
  }
});

// use value of search field to filter
var $quicksearch = $('.quicksearch').keyup(debounce(function() {
  qsRegex = new RegExp($quicksearch.val(), 'gi');
  $container.isotope({
    filter: function() {
      return qsRegex ? $(this).text().match(qsRegex) : true;
    }
  });
}));

// filter results on label click
$('#filter').on('click', 'label', function() {
  var filterValue = $(this).attr('data-filter');
  $('.quicksearch').val('')
  $container.isotope({
    filter: filterValue
  });
});

// sort results on label click
$('#sorts').on('click', 'label', function() {
  var sortByValue = $(this).attr('data-sort-by');
  $('.quicksearch').val('')
  $container.isotope({
    sortBy: sortByValue
  });
});
});
});
```

Is there any reason why the filters don't fire at first render? Can I do something different to make sure all grid items are loaded before I filter them?

Should I have some of these functions inside Template.CatchesList.onCreated instead? Or can I use a sort of timeout to delay the filters?